# Python: Speed up plots to be saved to pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the code below to create the `shap` dependence plots and save them to pdf. However, my dataframe has thousands of columns, so I am producing at least 2000 plots, each with different axis, and below already specifies `plt.pause(0.1)` and `plt.close()`. Yet, it still takes at least 12 hours to create all the plots and save them to a single pdf. This is too time consuming. Is there a better way to speed this up ?

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
def plotShapDependenceToFile(col_txt,pdf, shapValues_test, X_test, show):
    shap.dependence_plot(col_txt,shapValues_test[1],X_test,show=show) 
    pdf.savefig(bbox_inches = 'tight')
    plt.pause(0.1)
    plt.close()

shapValues_test = shapTreeExplainer.shap_values(X_test)
pdf =  PdfPages('output.pdf')
pd.Series(X_test.columns).apply(plotShapDependenceToFile,pdf=pdf, shapValues_test=shapValues_test, X_test=X_test, show=show)
pdf.close()
```

Comment: 2000 plots into a single pdf? With 10 plots per page, that would be 200 pages. Isn't it a bit much?

Comment: 1 plot per page. And that's what i am trying to achieve.